# `docker build ` result -> "could not read CA certificate: permission denied" via shell script, but can in terminal

Tags: bash, docker, sbt, minikube

I have script that build docker image in minikube.

```
#set -x
ASSEMBLY_NAME=$(basename ${1})
eval $(minikube docker-env)

echo "Current user is "$USER
echo "Current user groups  "$(id -Gn)
ls -la /home/user1/.minikube/certs/ca.pem

cp ${1} jdbc-puller/build/

docker build --build-arg ASSEMBLY_PATH=${ASSEMBLY_NAME} -t ${2} jdbc-puller/build
```

this script executed from sbt `sbt dockerBuild`.
Which is custom command:

```
  dockerBuild := {
      s"""./jdbc-puller/build/linux_build.sh ${assembly.value.getAbsolutePath}
       |organisation1/jdbc-puller:${gitCurrentBranch.value}_sha${gitHeadCommit.value
        .getOrElse("No_Head_Commit")}""".stripLineEnd.stripMargin !
    },
```

But i don't think that it's problem in sbt.
Because script output show right users and groups:

```
Current user is user1
Current user groups  user1 adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 1025 мар 23 18:35 /home/user1/.minikube/certs/ca.pem
could not read CA certificate "/home/user1/.minikube/certs/ca.pem": open /home/user1/.minikube/certs/ca.pem: permission denied
```

But if i run same command in shell directly:

```
 docker build --build-arg ASSEMBLY_PATH=navision-jdbc-puller-0.1.user1.prepare-to-development-028aaddff43890720432a2f27ad193a266ecf0ad.jar -t navision/jdbc-puller:prepare-to-development_sha028aaddff43890720432a2f27ad193a266ecf0ad navision-jdbc-puller/build
```

result is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  75.71MB
Step 1/7 : FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11.0.2
 ---> e711110a0ad5
Step 2/7 : ARG ASSEMBLY_PATH=target/scala-2.11/sbt-1.0/assembly.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 831efe890156
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR /opt/jdbc-puller
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cf252dc46acd
Step 4/7 : RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon:daemon", "."]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 843a834736ca
Step 5/7 : USER daemon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ea3b9894ceb5
Step 6/7 : COPY $ASSEMBLY_PATH /opt/jdbc-puller/assmebly.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 413ba469b2ef
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["java -jar /opt/jdbc-puller/assmebly.jar"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41c384cbcef6
Successfully built 41c384cbcef6
Successfully tagged navision/jdbc-puller:prepare-to-development_sha028aaddff43890720432a2f27ad193a266ecf0ad
```

evryhing work.
additional info

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/user1/.minikube/certs/ca.pem
# owner: user1
# group: user1
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

Please explain where I am wrong or at least what to next I can check.

Comment: ```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/user1/.minikube/certs/ca.pem
# owner: user1
# group: user1
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

```

Comment: I can confirm thst running script directly from terminal, has same behave as from sbt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i find a problem.
There was two bug.

One is mine,
I do not run in terminal `eval $(minikube docker-env)`.

Second one in minikube in ubuntu if minikube or dcoker instaled from snap.
here us answer for issue http://computerbryan.com/minikube-on-ubuntu.html.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed **docker using **snap**** and attempting to get **Minikube** running on ubuntu after executing -

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

**Fix -**

```
sudo nano /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.docker
```

**add :**

```
owner @{HOME}/.minikube/certs/* r,
```

**save and run on terminal-**

```
apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.docker


eval $(minikube docker-env)

docker ps
```

@snap isolates everything in AppArmor profiles

Comment: This makes perfect sense and worked instantly for me. Thank you!